# Why my menu is not showing when I guess a wrong word?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, menu

```
package hangman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int maxGuess = 5; // chances or life
        String wordTobeGuessed = "philippines";
        System.out.println("Welcome To Hangman!");
        System.out.println("You have 5 chances to guess the word!");
        System.out.println();

        // method calls
        guessTheWord(wordTobeGuessed, maxGuess);
    }

    /**
     * Function to manipulate the string
     * @param word           is the secret word
     * @param remainingGuess is the number of chances
     */
    public static void guessTheWord(String word, int remainingGuess) {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        char[] yourWord = word.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            yourWord[i] = '-';
            if (word.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                yourWord[i] = ' ';
            }
        }

        System.out.print(yourWord);

        // print out the remainingGuess which is 5
        System.out.println("  Your chance remaining = " + remainingGuess);

            ArrayList<Character> containerForChars = new ArrayList<Character>();

            // while the condition is true
            while (remainingGuess > 0) {
                System.out.println("Press 1 if you want guess the secret word  \nPress 2 to guess a 
                                letter");
                int num = userInput.nextInt();
                System.out.println();

                if (num == 1) {
                    checkTheWord(word, remainingGuess, yourWord);
                    break;
                }
```

When the program starts, the program asks the player to  choose between 1 and 2, 1 if you want to guess the secret word or 2 if you want to guess a letter. When I pressed 2, the program works perfectly fine, but when I pressed 1, the program will ask the player to type his/her guessed word as intended. If the guessed word matches the secret word, it works fine, but The problem is that if the player types a wrong guessed word, the Menu asking the player to press 1 to guess the word or 2 to guess a letter is not showing. It only asks the player to guess the secret word again.

```
                if (num == 2){
                System.out.println("Please Type a letter: ");
                char typedLetter = userInput.next().charAt(0); // char user input

                // check the arrayList to eliminate duplicates
                if (containerForChars.contains(typedLetter)) {
                    System.out.println("You have already tried that letter");
                    continue;
                }
                containerForChars.add(typedLetter); 

                if (word.contains(typedLetter + "")) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < word.length(); y++) {
                        if (word.charAt(y) == typedLetter) {
                            yourWord[y] = typedLetter; 
                        }
                    }

                } else {

                    remainingGuess--; 
                    checkThenumOfGuesses(remainingGuess, word);
                }

                if (word.equals(String.valueOf(yourWord))) { 
                    // prints out
                    System.out.println(yourWord);
                    System.out.println("Congratulations you guessed the Word!");
                    break; // stops the game
                }           
                if (remainingGuess != 0) {
                    System.out.print(yourWord);
                    System.out.println("  tries remaining = " + remainingGuess);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public static void checkTheWord(String word, int remainingGuess, char[] yourWord) {

        ArrayList<String>data= new ArrayList<String>();


        while (remainingGuess > 0) {
            System.out.println("Please write your guessed word");
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String guessWord = userInput.nextLine();

            if (data.contains(guessWord)) {
                System.out.println("You have already tried that word");
                continue;
            }
            data.add(guessWord);

            if (guessWord.equals(word)) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You have guessed the secret word!");
                break;
            } else {
                remainingGuess--;
                checkThenumOfGuesses(remainingGuess, word);
            }
            if (remainingGuess != 0) {
                System.out.print(yourWord);
                System.out.println("  tries remaining = " + remainingGuess);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method draw the hangman according to the number of remaining guesses
     * @param remainingGuess is the remaining chance of the player
     * @param word           is the secret word to be guessed
     */
    public static void checkThenumOfGuesses(int remainingGuess, String word) {

        if (remainingGuess == 0) {
            System.out.println("You Lose! R.I.P." +
                                    "\n ________" + 
                                    "\n |       |"+ 
                                    "\n |       Ö"+ 
                                    "\n |      /|\\"
                                  + "\n |      / \\" + 
                                    "\n |       " +
                                  "\n/|\\     ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The secret word is " + word);
        }

        else if (remainingGuess == 1) {
            System.out.println(" ________" 
                           + "\n |       |" + 
                             "\n |" 
                           + "\n |" + 
                             "\n |" + 
                             "\n |" + 
                             "\n/|\\");

        } else if (remainingGuess == 2) {

            System.out.println(" ________" + 
                            "\n |" + 
                            "\n |" + 
                            "\n |" + 
                            "\n |" + 
                            "\n |" + 
                            "\n/|\\");

        } else if (remainingGuess == 3) {
            System.out.println(" |" 
                           + "\n |" 
                           + "\n |" 
                           + "\n |" 
                           + "\n |"
                           + "\n |" 
                           + "\n/|\\");

        } else if (remainingGuess == 4) {
            System.out.println("/|\\");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is that you are always staying within the

```
while (remainingGuess > 0)
```

loop within your `checkTheWord` method. If the word is incorrectly entered, you continue the loop until there are no tries left.
Since you break after calling the `checkTheWord` method within your static `guessTheWord`method, the program will also always terminate after that. You should probably continue after using the method, and not loop within the `checkTheWord` method, since the loop in `guessTheWord` has the same loop condition anyway.

Comment: ```if (num == 1) {
checkTheWord(word, remainingGuess, yourWord);
continue;
}
``` When i run the program, still doesn't show the menu

Comment: This is only part of the solution i fear. Check within the `checkTheWord` method. You're looping inside of that function until there are no more tries too, with no way to break out of that loop.

Comment: @Millicent check WITHIN the `checkTheWord` method. You are looping inside there, and are always asking to enter the word. Your `data` field also needs to be static and global for it to work, if you remove that inner loop.

Comment: data field -  you mean my guessWord?

Comment: .. I removed the while loop inside my  * checkTheWord** method. Is there another way to break the loop when I guessed the correct word?

Comment: you could return a boolean from the `checkTheWord` method if the word was guessed correctly, so you can react to the result outside of the method, and break the outer loop.

Comment: Or you could set remainingGuess straight to zero, after guessing the correct word.

Comment: `if (guessWord.equals(word)) {
System.out.println("Congratulations! You have guessed the secret word!");
remainingGuess = 0;}`

Comment: Please write your guessed word
philippines
Congratulations! You have guessed the secret word!
Press 1 if you want guess the secret word  
Press 2 to guess a letter //im still getting this in the console.

Comment: With my proposed changes it should normally work. Maybe you have changed something else, like making the loop condition `while (remainingGuess >= 0)`? There should be no reason for the program to stay within the loop.

Comment: now i noticed that the remainingGuess is not decreasing by one everytime i guess a word incorrectly.

Comment: what do you mean by data field? is it the arrayList or the guessWord variable insidde the checkTheWord method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check again your **checkThenumOfGuesses**. You don't show menu asking player to choose 1 or 2.